# Assumption of homogeneity of variance when performing an independent t-test with bootstrap

Tags: t-test, bootstrap, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

An important assumption of the independent-samples t-test is that the two group's variances are equal in the population. To test whether these variances are different in the population, we can perform *Levene's Test for Equality of Variances* and adjust our *p-value* depending on whether homogeneity is met or not.

Now, should I still be concerned about this assumption when performing an independent t-test using bootstrapping? My sample is large.